# why I am not able to change directory in terminal?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter a name of directory" 
read name 
echo "Enter extension of file u want to open" 
read format 
a=`cd $name| ls | grep $format` 
echo "$a"
```

the question is why I am not able to change directories when am running it in terminal.

its showing a command does not exists.

Comment: each script you run does so in its own environment. If you are wondering why your main terminal that you ran your bash script from doesn't change directories that is why.

Comment: Giving what your outputs are and what you are expecting to see also helps other people understand your problem

Comment: you can replace your command with `find -type f -iname "*.$format" $name`

Comment: This smells strongly of homework to me.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `;` rather than `|`

```
a=`cd $name; ls | grep $format`
```

Although as mentioned above, bear in mind that you have *not* changed the directory the script is running in, merely in the shell formed by the backticks,

(Fixed typo, although there are better variants below)

Comment: This will hang at `grep $format`. As there is no input for `grep` to search, it will wait for input at `STDIN`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Correct; I think what the asker has in mind is `cd $name; ls | grep $format`.

Comment: But better still would be `cd $name && ls | grep \\.$format`, which will pick out only file extensions matching `$format`, and won't run the `ls | grep` pipeline at all if the `cd` fails, as for example if the path given doesn't exist.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid True enough; that'd likely be the best option, that or the `find` invocation in your comment above.